# Using strings or pointers to strings in struct

Tags: c, pointers, char, strcpy, pointer-to-array

I think I am missing something critical and I can't find an answer. If I want to use string in struct, is it better to use char arrays or pointers to them?
Following code works as intended, but raises warnings
"Warning    C4047   'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[3]"

when used with following definition of struct

```
typedef struct element {
    char name[20];
    char symb[3];
    double wt;
}element;
```

And following procedure for creating element

```
element e;
char name[20];
char symbol[3];
scanf("%s %s %lf", &name, &symbol, &e.wt);
strcpy(&e.name, &name);
strcpy(&e.symb, &symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the data types.

Change

```
 strcpy(&e.name, &name);
```

to

```
 strcpy(e.name, name);
```

and

```
scanf("%s %s %lf", &name, &symbol, &e.wt);
```

to

```
scanf("%s %s %lf", name, symbol, &e.wt);
```

That said, it's better to use `fgets()` to take user input. If you have to use `scanf()`, you must check for success of the `scanf()` call before using the scanned values.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into ```fgets()```, haven't heard about that one yet.